# Solve for a variable in the limit of integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do I solve for $x$ in an equation such as the following?
$$A = \int_0^x f(t) dt$$

I feel like I must of come across this at some point in my courses, but for the life of me I cannot remember. Is this something that is really easy, or just hard to do for a general function $f$?

Edit: A is a constant. I am looking to solve for $x$.

Comment: Are you asked to solve for $x$ or do you think you must in order to do something else?

Comment: Is A a constant or a function of x?

Comment: I think the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is what you're looking  for...http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html not fully sure if its relevant.

Comment: This is not homework, I am looking to just solve for $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't necessarily a unique solution, however consider the following:

We know via basic calculus that if $F$ is a function such that $F' = f$, then $$\int_0^x f(t)dt = F(x) - F(0)$$ so we can use this to get that $$F(x) = A+F(0).$$ If $F$ is invertible, then we get that $$x = F^{-1}(A+F(0)).$$

To see that it is not necessarily a unique solution, consider solving $$0 = \int_0^x \cos(t)dt.$$ Well, we are essentially solving $$0 = \sin(x)$$ and we know from trigonometry that we can have $x = n\pi$ for any $n\in Z$ as solutions.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.